# What are these devices on or adjacent to an airport taxi-way?

Tags: airport, taxiing, airport-markings

Can someone identify and provide some description of the objects marked in this photograph?

[image]

Especially those marked with yellow and red seem to be placed in the middle of a road and that seems to be making the road unusable. How can a plane or airport car go that way, if there are some devices placed in the middle? What am I missing?

Comment: You can find answers to your questions in chapters 2 and 3 of the [Aeronautical Information Manual](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf). [Chapter 2](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf#page=97) covers lighting and visual aids. [Chapter 3](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf#page=115) covers airport markings.

Comment: The double yellow lines indicate the edge of the taxi way.  The lights you see are on the shoulder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not a road that you are looking at, it is the edge of the runway / taxiway.

The double yellow lines are used to define the taxiway
edge from the shoulder or some other abutting paved
surface not intended for use by aircraft.

The blue lights in the yellow boxes are taxiway edge lights.

The poles next to the lights are blue reflective markers that will mark the taxiway in case the light fails. Systems for light control often work for groups of lights (e.g. sections of taxiways) or, if individually controlled, through a control signal on the power line powering the light. In the latter case, there is a small piece of electronics in each light housing controlling the intensity of that individual light and reporting back if the light fails.

The yellow objects in the blue boxes are signs. They indicate names of taxiways, runways, holding points etc. You see the backside of light casings, not the signs themselves. A bit further to the right you can see similar signs.

I am not sure what the item in the red box is.

Comment: A small side question -- if you please -- any idea why blue lights in the yellow boxes are each equipped with something that looks like an antenna? Remotely controlling each of light separately?

Comment: The poles next to the lights are blue reflective marker that will mark the taxiway in case the light will fail. Systems for light control often work for groups of lights (e.g. sections of taxiways) or, if individually controlled, through a control signal on the power line powering the light. In the latter case there is a small piece of electronics in each light housing controlling the intensity of that individual light and reporting back if the light fails. I don't know of any wireless system that use antennas for each light

Comment: The fronts of the signs can be seen to the right of the picture, above the plane's left wing (right wing from our viewing perspective).

Answer (score 14):

The item in the red box looks like a plastic stick that has reflective stickers on it which identify the taxiway edge even when there are several inches of snow (enough to bury the taxiway lights). Low-tech but it seems to work, and you can observe similar devices at many northern tier airports. Others can be seen near the blue boxes, slightly lower in the picture.

Comment: These are things Florida-based pilots can only see on the Internet. Thank you.